# Is it viable to mix two static libraries with different optimization levels?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, compiler-optimization

I have two static libraries named `libx.a` and `liby.a`.

`libx.a` is compiled with `gcc -g`; while `liby.a` is compiled with `gcc -O3`.

I want to link them two into a single executable.

Is it viable?

Is it harmful?

Comment: I would say yes, no problem.

Comment: In general, optimization is something that should not affect the interface of code, only change its implementation to something more efficient with respect to space or speed or whatever. However, compilers might make additional assumptions about the program and environment in order to optimize it (e.g., multi-threading is possible). I don't know a good example, but the optimizer might assume that all or no code is optimized, preventing interoperability. That's only a theoretical thought, though, I don't know if any compiler actually assumes that. So yes, in general, it's viable.

Comment: Think about it this way. The standard C library is inplemented largely as an object library, and it is shipped optimized, however running unoptimized  programs linked with it is completey OK.

Comment: As long as the ABI is the same, why should there be a problem? Is there any indication in the ABI which says that different optimisation levels may use different conventions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is viable, it isn't harmful as long as the optimizations don't change the ABI (of function calls, or of floating point arithmetic/representation, etc.). Although even in those cases, I believe all necessary information is already compiled in or the linker resolves the issues.