# optimization flag e.g. /O2 = optimize at File / Project / or Solution level?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

I have some visual-studio projects :-

- `B1` (no optimization)
- `B2` (optimization `/O2`) : use `B1` as static library
- `B3` (no optimization) : use `B1` and `B2` as static library

What is the optimization effect on `B3/main.cpp`?

Would `B3` here be compiled faster (and .exe has worse performance) than a case that `B3` also `/O2` ?

I play with `/O2` many times, but still confuse about the results.
I feel that the flag is project-level.

If I expect to not modify `B2` often but modify `B3` often , it may be better for performance & minimum compile time to set `B2 = /O2` & `B3 = no optimization`. (?)

Sorry if it is a newbie question.  I reluctant to ask it for a few years.

Official reference (useless) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o1-o2-minimize-size-maximize-speed?view=vs-2019

Comment: Not clear what you tried to ask. What you trying to say by "use B1 and B2"? Btw yes `/O2` is project level flag.

Comment: @Atul Sorry, I mean static libraries.  I edited my question.  Thank.

Comment: You need to be careful mixing unoptimized, debug static libraries with optimized static libraries within the same application -- I don't believe it will work anyway at link time.  You need to compile all of your modules with the same flags.

Comment: There is no single answer. Optimising for performance often increases compile times and file sizes.Static linking doesn't affect compilation times, but can increase link times (e.g. copying `B1` into `B2`). The impact on program startup and runtime performance depends on how the OS loads programs into memory. Generally speaking, I'd use the same optimisation settings throughout because the cost of human effort to manage a build process that builds different parts of a system in different ways probably exceeds any measurable benefits in terms of build time or runtime performance.

Answer (score 0):

`/O2` is project level flag.

For your project B3 it does not matter optimization levels of libraries being used (B1 and B2). As long as the ABI is the same you can use libraries of different optimizations as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40610134/1911652).

Now let's answer your questions.

> Would B3 here be compiled faster (and .exe has worse performance) than a case that B3 also /O2 ?

Optimization flag is about speed and size of binary and not about compilation time. `B3` executable will be faster if you specify `/O2` to `B3`

> If I expect to not modify B2 often but modify B3 often , it may be
>   better for performance & minimum compile time to set B2 = /O2 & B3 =
>   no optimization. (?)

Again, optimization flag is not used to reduce compile time. For better performance (speed) of B3 executable compile it with `/O2`

Comment: Hmm.  I am quite sure that "Optimize = longer compilation time".

Comment: @cppBeginner: It may or may not be a side effect of optimization flag set. But optimization is not meant to use for reducing or stretching compile time.

Comment: Thus, in my example, each project will use its own flag independently?  Therefore your answer on my "(?)" is "yes"?

Comment: By the way, I know that "/O2 increases compilation time" is a (unfavorable) side effect.  No need to clarify that, thank. :)